# Hide applied job offers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs, advertising

Can the job ads from [careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com) on [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) be hidden for jobs which are applied already?

I have applied to jobs but still I'm seeing those same job ads. Can this be done?

Comment: I apologize for not seeing this sooner. We actually think this is a great idea, and pretty easy to implement, so we're going to do it. We'll let you know when it's done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been implemented. Due to the nature of how our systems communicate, it might take up a little while for it to take effect for any given user.

If you still see job ads for listings you've applied to after 24 hours, please go ahead and post here on meta. Thanks!